# In MIPS pipeline, does the ID/EX register hold the value of the registers, or the address of the register

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

Say I have a MIPS pipeline with 32bits words. The pipeline stages are IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB, and there is no forwarding.

My question is: When executing the ID stage, say for a `sub` command, are the values of the registers stored in the ID/EX register, or does the ID/EX register simply store the address of the register (5 bits) and then proceeds to read them from the register file at the EX step?

This question was formed while I was studying my class notes, and I came upon the following image:

[image]

Personally, in the second line of the image (the `sub` command) I was expecting the ID step to be placed after the stalls, so the WB step of `lw` is first executed, and then the ID step of `sub` can get the updated value of the registers.

But, the image shows that the ID step of `sub` can actually be before the WB step of `lw` causing me to believe that the actual value of the registers are not stored in the ID/EX register, since if that was the case, the values propagated to EX would be not valid.

Comment: Reading from the register file happens during ID; after that it's just values, whether it's the EX or MEM stage (for a store) that needs the values.  Values can also come from bypass forwarding, not the reg file at all, which is another reason to have values, not references to the register file.

Answer (score 3):

We have discovered that your instructor is proposing a hypothetical processor.  That's ok, hypotheticals are used all the time.  It's just not the usual MIPS.

The answer below speaks to the classic MIPS pipelined processor.

---

This diagram looks like the processor is using both 2 stalls and a bypass, which is overkill, if you ask me.  The load data is ready at the end of the MEM stage in cycle 4.  The EX stage for the `sub` can execute in cycle 5 with only 1 stall — there's no benefit to waiting until cycle 6, because the data is ready at the beginning of cycle 5, and in cycle 6 *a bypass is still needed* (the last alternative would be to re-run the `sub`s ID stage in cycle 6 to pick up the load data, though that would cost 3 stall cycles, but eliminate the need for a bypass).

However, to answer your question about the contents of the pipeline register, the ID/EX pipeline stage register sits on the boundary between ID and EX, and holds whatever is computed earlier e.g. by IF and ID, that is needed by any stage later, e.g. EX, MEM, and WB.

This includes both register lookup value as well as register numbers.  RAW hazards do not always happen so the register values are needed for the case there is no RAW hazard at the moment.

The register numbers are used in detection of the presence of RAW hazards, by comparing register target numbers from prior instructions with register source numbers in the current instruction.

So, the answer is both: the pipeline stage registers will have 32-bit register values and 5-bit register numbers.  This data is also forwarded from EX to MEM b/c there are also MEM/MEM hazards that can be avoided using bypass.

In handling of exceptions, like bad address in load or store, and also for taken branches, the program counter is required, so the program counter is probably forwarded from IF to ID to EX to MEM, via those pipeline registers.
  From ID on, control signals will also be forwarded.  WB, for example, needs to know RegWrite (yes/no) and WriteReg (5-bit reg number).

Comment: based on my professor, there is no bypassing (aka forwarding) used in the processor. If bypassing was available, then I completely agree with you, but now that it's not, the only way to make sense of this image is to consider that the EX stage actually reads the updated value of the registers.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, though I've never heard of that being done.  That will incur a time penalty on EX stage, since then it has to redo work that would have taken place in ID in a standard pipeline, and that has to finish before the usual part of EX can start.  If that's the case, then perhaps the 32-bit register values are not in the ID/EX pipeline register -- but again this is a hypothetical that is rather unusual.

Comment: Makes me wonder about MEM and if it also re-reads the source register for `sw`.  That would be consistent with this approach but also problematic since that adds another read port to the register file.  The alternative would be for EX to read the registers and forward the store source to MEM, similar to how the normal pipelined processor does this with ID & EX.

Comment: I do not think that MEM is supposed to re-read the source register, since if that's the case then it needs to re-perform the offset addition to the (possibly updated) register value. Anyway, personally I agree with your initial comment and I would expect the EX stage to actually just grab the value from the ID/EX register value, and that is probably the way I am going to use it (at least after this semester ends :-) )